# how to center my camera on my player LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to position my camera on my player **sprite** but when I'm doing that my sprite move two time faster

Deplacement function :

```
if(keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
        //camera.translate(-16, 0);
        spritePlayer.setPosition(spritePlayer.getX() -16, spritePlayer.getY());
    }
```

Camera function :

```
camera.position.set(spritePlayer.getX()+(spritePlayer.getWidth()*2) ,spritePlayer.getY()+(spritePlayer.getHeight()*2) ,0);
camera.update();
```

Thanking you in advance, 
Palpatoune

Comment: `camera.position.x = spritePlayer.getX() + spritePlayer.getWidth() / 2f;` `camera.position.y = spritePlayer.getY() + spritePlayer.getHeight() / 2f;`

Comment: Also, you should never move objects without using delta time, or the speed will be unpredictable. Use a speed, multiply it by delta time and add the result to the position.

Comment: Tenfour i don't understand what is the "/2f"

Comment: i've just realized that my charater who is basicaly a sprite moving by himself when my camera move. it explain the fact that my character move two times faster when my camera move. How can i separate my charater movement and my camera movement ?
thank you in advance,
Palpatoune

Comment: If you're using a sprite, its position is in the bottom left corner. So if you want to get the position of the center of a sprite, you have to add half the width and height to the x and y.

Comment: If you're player moves in response to the camera moving, that's a bug. I can't answer how to fix that bug without seeing the code. Just find the lines where you are changing your sprite's position and make sure the camera isn't part of your formula.

Comment: `2` is an int. `2f` is a float. I usually specify the `f` when I use floating point numbers so there can be no confusion. It avoids bugs related to doing integer division. For example `(3 / 2) * 1000` evaluates to 1000 whereas `(3f / 2f) * 1000` evaluates to 1500.

Comment: i've find a way to solve my problem only by using this line player.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
Thank you for all your comments